# Kill subprocess before program loads

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am opening a process with Popen and passing in some arguments (--name) - this argument prints some information to the terminal. This information is loaded into the name variable.

The problem I have is that if the file/script doesn't have a response to --name, it loads that program. I want to kill the process before the application loads.

In any case, all I want is a response from --name. Even if there is a response, I want the program to terminate as soon as that gets loaded into name.

```
    output_name = Popen([file, '--name'], stdout=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
    name = output_name.stdout.read()
    output_name.terminate()
```

I tried terminate() and kill() as shown above and neither seemed to help.

Comment: You can use command `taskkill /f /im process_name` with `subprocess.Popen'

Comment: Popen(['taskkill', '/f', '/im', file])   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'taskkill'

Comment: @ChandaKorat   above

Comment: Try this one `subprocess.Popen("taskkill /IM process_name /f",
                               stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                               stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                               shell=True)`